# Set variable resetting upon function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to create a React.js app that cycles through flashcards in a random order.
 
To do this, I have a set declared to hold previously stored cards and a function to cycle through cards. However, after adding elements to the set in a function, none of the elements are retained once the function is called again.

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import FlippableCard from './components/flippable-card.jsx'
// import 


const App = () => {
  const cards = [{question: "2+2", answer: "4"}, {question: "3+2", answer: "5"}, {question: "4+5", answer: "9"}]
  var reviewedCards = new Set([])
  const [card, setCard] = useState(0)

  // Optimize this later
  const changeCard = (reviewedCards) => {
    var newCard = card

    // console.log(reviewedCards.size, cards.length)
    // if (reviewedCards.size == cards.length) {
    //   reviewedCards.clear()
    // }
    console.log(reviewedCards.size)
    reviewedCards.add(card)
    console.log(reviewedCards.size)


    let text = "";
    for (var entry of reviewedCards.values()) {
      text += entry;
    }
    console.log("Set " + text)

    while (reviewedCards.has(newCard)){
      newCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
    }

    setCard(newCard)
    // console.log(newCard)
    reviewedCards.add(newCard)
    console.log(reviewedCards.size)
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <FlippableCard front={cards[card].question} back={cards[card].answer}/>
      <button onClick={changeCard}></button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I ran the function once and the end result was a set populated with 3 elements. After running the function again, the set started off with 0 elements again rather than retaining a size of 3. I suspect it to be an issue with the scope of the set.

Comment: The value is re-declared on every render.  You need to store the value *in state*, exactly like you already do with your other state value.

Comment: Your changeCard function is written to accept reviewedCards as a parameter (instead of using the global reviewedCards variable).  Because you don’t pass any parameter when you call it, reviewedCards within the function is going to be undefined.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the code accordingly.